# Antarctica on Google Chart API

Tags: api, charts, geo

Antarctica is really missing from Google Geo Charts? I have to display some info on world map and I need Antarctica also. What other alternatives I have?

Comment: Hi, you can add a country by like this  ['Country name', 'value']

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no place for Antarctica on Google Geo Chart. So if you wanted to show Antarctica too then you have to go for other library such as SharpMap. This is available for you on NuGet also. Try that.